# Unable to pass data between MasterVC to DetailVC in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass `data(_claimReportToDetailView)` from `viewDidLoad` (of `MasterVC`) to `DetailVC`. It's always `null`.

```
@interface LAMasterViewController ()
{
    NSArray *_claimReports;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _claimReports = [[LADataModelController getSingleton] getClaimReportsOrderedByAccessedDate];
    LADetailViewController *detailViewController = [[LADetailViewController alloc] init];
    detailViewController.claimReportToDetailView = (LAClaimReport *)_claimReports[0];
    NSLog(@"claim%@",detailViewController.claimReportToDetailView); // captures here properly.
}

@interface LADetailViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic ) LAClaimReport *claimReportToDetailView;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"sdfdf%@", _claimReportToDetailView); // logs null always.
}
```

Comment: Can you show code where you add detailViewController to view hierarchy.

Comment: its on StoryBoard Greg. The detailVC is opening properly

Comment: @keshav No need, that's the default for object properties anyway.

Comment: I would also avoid direct iVar access in favour of using properties. i.e. `self.claimReportToDetailView` instead of `_claimReportToDetailView`. There is even a Clang warning you can turn on to flag such access.

Answer (score 1):

Your `viewDidLoad` seems strange. You have this line:

```
LADetailViewController *detailViewController = [[LADetailViewController alloc]init];
```

Yet you say that the view controller is on the storyboard.

I think what is happening is that you are creating this VC, and setting it's property, but the Storyboard is loading a completely new VC, for which you haven't set the property.

Usually, the way you pass information to VCs on Storyboards is in the `prepareForSegue:` method.

Comment: Indeed and `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` would be used to get access to the view controller in order to set-up the data to present/edit.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yep, but then the masterVC would be responsible for presenting the detailVC.

Comment: look into the first section (the approach i want to follow) http://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/02/16/ios-app-passing-data-between-view-controllers/  i don't have any segues to pass data here.

Comment: @LUI Rather than make me read some random blog post that you are following, you could just update your question with details of the approach you are trying to follow.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your project. Give it a try

```
//Allocating LADetailViewController instance
LADetailViewController *detailViewController = [[LADetailViewController alloc]init];

//Connecting it the specified VC on storyboard
detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourVCID"];

//Now the connection is set, so pass the data you need
detailViewController.claimReportToDetailView = (LAClaimReport *)_claimReports[0];

//Depending on present or push you should try one of the 2 lines
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
//or
[self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: To be clear, the view is not set here. Although the VC is instantiated here, the view is not yet loaded.

Comment: Yes you are right I meant to say connection. Question updated

Comment: though it passes the data but the DetailVC is pushed twice and on the screen masterVC is replaced by DetailVC.

Comment: Thats happens only if you have connected with segue master with detail VC. Remove segue and pass the data this way or try @greg Solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the data to the details view controller in prepareForSeque method in master view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) { //<-make shire the segue identifier match one in storyboard
        _claimReports = [[LADataModelController getSingleton] getClaimReportsOrderedByAccessedDate] ;
        LADetailViewController *vc = (LADetailViewController*)[sender destinationViewController];
        vc.claimReportToDetailView = (LAClaimReport *)_claimReports[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because whenever you navigate from one UIViewController to other, it is initialized again, so rather than setting value in viewDidLoad, try to set value on the event when you perform navigation and make navigation through code rather than with segue.